# Deployment - node selector per replica

Tags: kubernetes

How to express : "Yo kubernetes, run 3 replicas, but at-least 1 of them must be running on a node with label `cost=expensive`"

Lets say I have 2 sets of worker nodes(minions).

Set 1 with label `cost=expensive`. Set 2 `cost=cheap`.

I want to run a Deployment with 3 replica such that at-least one of them is scheduled on a Set 1, and I don't care where the other 2 replicas are launched.

notes:-

1. I am running Kubernetes `1.6.2`.
2. Example use case: Set 2 consists of spot instances which can die at any-moment. I would like atleast 1 pod running on on-demand instance.
3. I've read the [Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) guide which lets me (a) (`podAntiAffinity`) spread pods across nodes; or (b) (`nodeSelector` or `nodeAffinity`) put soft/hard constraints on what selectors *all* pods will run.
4. I could run the pods on 2 separate deployments, one with 1 replica and  `nodeSelector` set to `cost=expensive`, but that makes it messy.

Comment: Run 2 deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run 2 deployments, pods in same deployment or replica set means same configuration, spread them to different kinds of custom node set is not the case. If you want them provide service together, you can set correct labels and make them work behind same service.

BTW, you can do this job by customizing scheduler policy, while that is too expansive.